# JpaRepository mistakes custom interface as property

Tags: spring, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

For general spring JpaRepository DAO (**no** spring-boot) , if the interface extends a custom interface , spring will mistake the interface methods as object's properties .

For example

```
interface ILocalDateTime {
  fun getLocalDateTime() : LocalDateTime
}

interface UserDaoCustom : ILocalDateTime {
    // query functions skipped
}

interface UserDao : JpaRepository<User, Long>, UserDaoCustom

class UserImpl : UserDaoCustom {

  @PersistenceContext
  private lateinit var em: EntityManager

  override fun getLocalDateTime(): LocalDateTime {
    return LocalDateTime.now()
  }

  // query functions skipped
}
```

This is a simplified `UserDao`. `UserDaoCustom` extends `ILocalDateTime` which contains a method `getLocalDateTime` .

Note : `localDateTime` is not a field of `User`.

At runtime, `JpaRepository` will mistake `getLocalDateTime` (or `localDateTime` ?) as `User`'s field , and throws such exception :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: 
Could not create query for public abstract java.time.LocalDateTime foo.ILocalDateTime.getLocalDateTime()! 
Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.time.LocalDateTime foo.ILocalDateTime.getLocalDateTime()! 
No property getLocalDateTime found for type User!; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Failed to create query for method public abstract java.time.LocalDateTime foo.ILocalDateTime.getLocalDateTime()! 
No property getLocalDateTime found for type User!
```

Environment :

```
Kotlin 1.6.20
Spring 5.3.19
spring-data-jpa 2.5.11
```

How to solve this problem ? (with able or unable to modify `ILocalDateTime`'s code)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is about naming and how Spring pick up implementations of repository extensions.

**TLDR;**
Change name of your implementation from `UserImpl` to `UserDaoCustomImpl`.

I have checked a similar setup and using your naming fails with the exact same error, but naming it "right" makes it work as expected

```
public interface ILocalDateTime {
    LocalDateTime getLocalDateTime();
}

@Repository
public interface UserDao extends UserDaoCustom, JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}

public interface UserDaoCustom extends ILocalDateTime{
}

@Repository
public class UserDaoCustomImpl implements UserDaoCustom {
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime getLocalDateTime() {
        return LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

and tests

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
class UserRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Test
    public void savesUser() {
        userDao.save(new User());
    }

    @Test
    public void bazzinga() {
        assert userDao.getLocalDateTime() != null;
        System.out.println("Bazzinga!"+userDao.getLocalDateTime());
    }


}
```

yelds
[image]